# What AWS SDK should I choose?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am a newbie on Amazon Web Service. I have a task that setup then build a web service that provide APIs to Mac OS, iOS, Android client. There are some APIs and Database need to be kept in secure. I see that AWS support multiple platform such as Java, .Net, PHP,... It also support many Database Management System. Not yet, there are 2 special SDK for Android and iOS app.

So, What should I choose (Java, .Net, PHP,...) to carry out my task? Does AWS support all webservice protocol? Does it support secure webservice?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS doesn't provide secured web services - it provides platforms on which you can run your secure web services.  You should choose the platform / language / tools that you are most experienced to build your application with your web services and databases.  You should check that you can run all the parts you need on AWS (which is very likely).  AWS can help with security with firewalls and ELB-stored certificates.

For such broad access (ios, android, others), I can recommend REST-based web services since they are easy for all sorts of clients to reach (but it does depend on what you are trying to get your clients to do).  Make sure you buy a SSL certificate from a well-established provider (otherwise you clients may have trouble connecting to your secure services).

Good luck.

Comment: Why did you recommend Rest-based? How about SOAP protocol?

Comment: SOAP is fine if 1) you are used to it and 2) you know you can implement the client-side easily on the different target platforms you mentioned (iOS, MacOS and Android).  I mention REST because I have seen the same REST end-points support browser, objective-C and Java clients well.